# transition opacity not working when loading page

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition, opacity

I seem to have an issue with the opacity of my page pre-loader, when it loads, the page content shows in the back and is not hidden.

I'm not sure what seem to be the issue, or is my code wrong?

```
<div class="loader">
      <div class="name-load">
        <h2 data-text="NedhalM .">NedhalM .</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS for the pre loading page and h2 animation

```
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: black;
  transition: opacity 0.75s 4s, visibility 0.75s 4s;
}

.loader--hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

along with the animation of the name on its own, and this is the Javascript i used

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");

    loader.classList.add("loader--hidden");

    loader.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
        document.body.removeChild(loader);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `opacity` value (`opacity: 1`) in the rule for `.loader`

Comment: Hello, thank you in advance
transition: opacity 0.75s 4s, visibility 0.75s 4s;
opacity: 1;
Like so? It still shows the background >< i'm sorry for troubeling you.

Comment: No, as an extra parameter, independent from `transition`: `opacity: 1;`